# Convert this .htaccess directive to nginx for me

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

```
<Files urllist.txt>
    order allow,deny
    Allow from xx.xx.91.29
</Files>
```

Comment: If you need somebody to do your work - hire a developer! You could have at least accepted the answer of @AlexD!

Answer (score 5):

This will translate to following in nginx config:

```
location = /path/to/urllist.txt {
  allow xx.xx.91.29;
  deny all;
}
```

See documentation for [location](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAccessModule#allow) and [allow](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) directives.